# Apply directive to previously hidden content when shown

Tags: css, angularjs

I have two divs on my page both with the same directive. One is called medium and one is called large.

```
<div class="mediumLayout">
   <div ng-controller="PortfolioListCtrl" list-portfolios></div>
</div>
<div class="largeLayout">
   <div ng-controller="PortfolioListCtrl" list-portfolios></div>
</div>
```

Using CSS I show or hide one or the other depending on the browser width:

```
.largeLayout {
display: none;
}

@media (min-width: 2000px) {
  .largeLayout {
      display: block;
   }   
   .mediumLayout {
       display: none;
   }
}
```

When I resize my browser it shows the large but the content isn't rendered by Angular unless I trigger some other event.

Is there an easy way to trigger the controller to render when the display changes?

Comment: You can trigger something on the `$window` `resize` event. I setup [this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ovDVEjSSDuxGSSzbWPMT?p=preview) to see if I could replicate the problem, but I couldn't. Are they any obvious adjustments you can make to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Interesting. I'm trying to see if I can tweak the plunker to reproduce the issue but so far it is working.

Comment: You are correct, it does work just fine. By editing your plunker and slowly adding in my code I found I had a tab-pane class that wasn't active which was the issue. :P Thanks for your help!